# Why do I get error 201 Procedure or Function expects parameter which was not supplied?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the code below I get an error message:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[stp_DespatchedJob]
        @JobStatusId = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

> Msg 201, Procedure stp_DespatchedJob, Line 0
>   Procedure or Function 'stp_DespatchedJob' expects parameter '@jobId', which was not supplied

What does this mean? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are trying to call a stored procedure that has a required parameter that you are not passing.  I can't tell you exactly what your syntax should look like without knowing the parameters of the procedure.  You will have to look at the parameters on the procedure and make sure all of the parameters without defaults are passed in the `EXEC` statement.  But to add the @jobId to your `EXEC` statement it would look something like this:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[stp_DespatchedJob]
        @JobStatusId = NULL,
        @jobId=7
```